# Kill my application after finish

Tags: android, kill

How to kill my application after call finish?

(i can see my app in HTC's phone, but i finished that activity anyway)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quitting an application - is that frowned upon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's really no need for this, Android automatically decides when to kill apps. However, you can, if you need to, kill it using:

```
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
```

Comment: Google has repeatedly advised not to do this in production code.

Comment: The problem with this call is that some devices will recognise this as an crashed app and will restart the app in the background this means killing the app uses more resources then leaving it alone.

Answer (score 0):

this.finish() terminates my applications fine.

Have you looked in LogCat to see if anything is reported when you execute finish()??

Comment: finish keeps the application in the background - You just don't see it. If you have a background thread running, it will keep on running until the device will need more resources and kills the app.